# Performance issue with Promises, setTimeout, async/await on Edge

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

Is there anything inherently wrong with the following mixed use of asnyc/await, promise, and setInterval? It's working as desired, but the performance is terrible on Edge. My test case runs in about 3.5 sec in Chrome, but takes over 2 min in Edge. Note that this is a method from a TypeScript class.

```
public async exportPdf(sourceGraph: IGraph, filters: EntityFilter) {
        if (sourceGraph) {
            ...snip....
            for (let verticalPageIndex = 0; verticalPageIndex < pagesHighWithMargins; verticalPageIndex++) {
                for (let horizontalPageIndex = 0; horizontalPageIndex < pagesWideWithMargins; horizontalPageIndex++) {
                    // run with setTimeout so we can process other events between pages and prevent locking up the browser
                    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0)).then(async () => {
                        ...snip...
                        const svgElement = await exporter.exportSvgAsync(exportComponent) as SVGElement;
                         ....snip - expensive code to convert SVG to PDF page...
                    });
                }
            }

            return jsPdf.output('datauristring');
        } else {
            return new Promise((_, reject) => {
                reject(new Error('graph argument is null'));
            });
        }
    }
```

Obviously I'm a newbie with JS and TS, but I've been around long enough to know that mixing 3 different techniques for managing async operations is probably wrong. :-)

Comment: `public` keyword is reserved in JavaScript. Remove that and run it in Edge again. Also `async` needs to be `async function` unless itt's an arrow function

Comment: @zer00ne this is actually from a TypeScript class. Sorry for any confusion! I've updated the description and tags.

Comment: Don't use `.then()` with `await`, don't pass an `async` function as a callback. Just `await new Promise(/* timeout */); … const svgElement = await …`.

Comment: What does `exporter.exportSvgAsync` do? Is it not asynchronous in itself, doesn't it prevent the browser from locking up already?

Comment: Are you saying that without the `setTimeout(resolve, 0)`, your code runs at the same speed in both browsers? Then try doing that less often, such as only in the outer loop.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the ideas! I'm away from the computer for a couple of days, but will test them all as soon as I can. The ```exporter.exportSvgAsync``` is from a commercial third-party library to export a graph to SVG. I assume it is actually async as implied, but I will retest if that alone will prevent licking browser.

Comment: Author of the TypeScript class needs to be spoken to!

Comment: @Roamer-1888 The author appreciates being spoken to so speak away and I'll ensure he gets the message. 

Comment: Ha! I'm just reinforcong the points Bergi made in his first comment above, namely that mixing `.then()` with `await` should be avoided, and that `.then()` should never need to be passed an asyncFunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing out this question because I've isolated my primary issue -- *performance when using the Edge browser* -- to a library I'm using to convert SVG to PDF and not my use of promises, setTimeout, or async/await, but any further insight on the additional findings below is appreciated!

@Bergi's suggestions are much appreciated, but I'm probably still be missing something. If I don't include the lines after `await new Promise(...)` inside the `then()`, my loops complete before I've generated the content of my PDF pages, which causes the next steps -- *exporting the complete PDF content as a string and saving to disk* -- to fail. I need this loop to complete synchronously so I get all the PDF content in the correct order. The only reason I'm using `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0))` is to slightly improve the browser's responsiveness during the loop, which is working pretty much as shown in the original post.

I did removed the `async` from the `then`'s callback and switched to a synchronous version of the `exportSvg` function and it's working well. Simply awaiting the call to `exporter.exportSvgAsync` without enclosing it in a `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0)).then(...)` did not allow the browser to be responsive at all inside the loop though.